# Set operations on matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, set, union, intersection

I am currently writing code in R that hinges heavily on using set operations on matrices. I am wondering if there are any packages or pre-existing functions out there that can compare every value in a row of a matrix. For example, if I have the following two matrices:

```
A1                     A2
1   1 -1.579122144     10  0.577115944
2   2 -1.620980244     11  1.263320594
3   3 -1.156350422     12 -0.524403635
4   4  0.948909066     13 -1.363554588
5   5 -0.719925025     14  1.698710773
6   6  0.642472705     15  0.957670227
7   7  0.611488905     16 -1.579122144
8   8 -1.048742921     17 -1.620980244
9   9 -0.006137041     18 -1.156350422
10 10  0.577115944     19  0.948909066
11 11  1.263320594     20 -0.719925025
12 12 -0.524403635     21  0.642472705
13 13 -1.363554588     22  0.611488905
14 14  1.698710773     23 -1.048742921
15 15  0.957670227     24 -0.006137041
```

the hypothetical intersection function would return something like:

```
>intersect(A1,A2)
10  0.5771159
11  1.2633206
12 -0.5244036
13 -1.3635546
14  1.6987108
15  0.9576702
```

Perhaps the `subset` function could work here, but I am unsure how to implement it. Any help with a function for set differences, intersections, and unions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do all of your matrices have only one column? If not, how do you define these operations in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Edited to add 2 Packages: `sqldf`, `dplyr`

The output that you require can be achieved through the `sqldf` package. Convert your matrix to a dataframe. Therefore:

```
A1<-data.frame(x=c(-1.579122144,-1.62098024,-1.156350422,0.948909066,-0.719925025,0.642472705,0.611488905,-1.048742921,-0.006137041,0.577115944,1.263320594,-0.524403635,-1.363554588,1.698710773,0.957670227), id=1:15)
A2<-data.frame(x=c(0.577115944,1.263320594,-0.524403635,-1.363554588,1.698710773,0.957670227,-1.579122144,-1.62098024,-1.156350422,0.948909066,-0.719925025,0.642472705,0.611488905,-1.048742921,-0.006137041), id=10:24)
```

Now use the `sqldf` package:

```
library (sqldf)

sqldf("select * from A1 intersect select * from A2")
```

which will give you your output:

```
x id
1 -1.3635546 13
2 -0.5244036 12
3  0.5771159 10
4  0.9576702 15
5  1.2633206 11
6  1.6987108 14
```

**OR**

You can use the `dplyr` package and use the `intersect` function:

```
library(dplyr)

intersect(A1,A2, by="x")
```

Both these 2 packages should have functions for `union` `setdiff` etc

Answer (score 0):

Base R `merge()` does this, with the only caveat that it forces matrices to data.frames, which is why the column names `V1` and `V2` appear in the following output:

```
A1 <- matrix(c(1:15,-1.579122144,-1.62098024,-1.156350422,0.948909066,-0.719925025,0.642472705,0.611488905,-1.048742921,-0.006137041,0.577115944,1.263320594,-0.524403635,-1.363554588,1.698710773,0.957670227),15L);
A2 <- matrix(c(10:24,0.577115944,1.263320594,-0.524403635,-1.363554588,1.698710773,0.957670227,-1.579122144,-1.62098024,-1.156350422,0.948909066,-0.719925025,0.642472705,0.611488905,-1.048742921,-0.006137041),15L);
o <- lapply(list(A1,A2),capture.output); cat(paste0('A1',paste0(collapse='',rep(' ',nchar(o[[1]][1])-2L+3L)),'A2'),do.call(paste,c(o,sep='   ')),sep='\n'); ## unnecessarily complex line to print the two matrices side-by-side
## A1                        A2
##       [,1]         [,2]         [,1]         [,2]
##  [1,]    1 -1.579122144    [1,]   10  0.577115944
##  [2,]    2 -1.620980240    [2,]   11  1.263320594
##  [3,]    3 -1.156350422    [3,]   12 -0.524403635
##  [4,]    4  0.948909066    [4,]   13 -1.363554588
##  [5,]    5 -0.719925025    [5,]   14  1.698710773
##  [6,]    6  0.642472705    [6,]   15  0.957670227
##  [7,]    7  0.611488905    [7,]   16 -1.579122144
##  [8,]    8 -1.048742921    [8,]   17 -1.620980240
##  [9,]    9 -0.006137041    [9,]   18 -1.156350422
## [10,]   10  0.577115944   [10,]   19  0.948909066
## [11,]   11  1.263320594   [11,]   20 -0.719925025
## [12,]   12 -0.524403635   [12,]   21  0.642472705
## [13,]   13 -1.363554588   [13,]   22  0.611488905
## [14,]   14  1.698710773   [14,]   23 -1.048742921
## [15,]   15  0.957670227   [15,]   24 -0.006137041
merge(A1,A2);
##   V1         V2
## 1 10  0.5771159
## 2 11  1.2633206
## 3 12 -0.5244036
## 4 13 -1.3635546
## 5 14  1.6987108
## 6 15  0.9576702
```

You can restore matrixness with `as.matrix()`, and remove the column names with `unname()`, if you want.